# Veth interface configuration persistent

Tags: centos, networking, virtual-interface

How to configure the veth interface on CentOS 7 in such a way to make it state persistent after system reboot?
For example:

veth configuration:

```
# create veth pair and assing IP address.
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip addr add 10.1.0.1/24 dev veth0
ip addr add 10.1.0.2/24 dev veth1


# bring up the interfaces
ip link set veth0 up
ip link set veth1 up
```

These settings are saved after network service restart but are not saved after system restart.
In the RedHat documentation does not mention now to write ifcfg-vethX interface configuration file or ifup-veth and ifdown-veth scripts for the veth interfaces that should be in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a configuration file for your veth0 interface and place it in
`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-veth0:`

```
DEVICE="veth0"
TYPE="veth"
DEVICETYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR="10.1.0.1"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

You also need to copy these scripts and place them in

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
```

directory on your system:
Samples:

- https://github.com/LanetNetwork/initscripts-veth/blob/master/ifup-veth
- https://github.com/LanetNetwork/initscripts-veth/blob/master/ifdown-veth

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to append the necessary commands to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. This will be executed when the system boots (by the `rc-local.service` systemd unit).

1. Create the file `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` if it doesn't already exist.
2. Make sure the file is executable (`chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local)
3. Add the `ip` commands in your question.